# Photobucket iOS API Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, photobucket

I'm trying to integrate Photobucket iOS API with my project. I requested and already have consumer key and secret. But I have a problem with authentication (may be there is will be problems with upload). Please look at my code. 
At first init photobucket manager:

```
manager = [[PhotobucketAPI alloc] initWithConsumerKey:photobucketConsumerKey
                                               consumerSecret:photobucketConsumerSecret
                                          globalErrorDelegate:self];
```

Then request authentication:

```
[manager loginDirectAndStoreForUsername:login
                                           password:pass
                                           delegate:self
                                 didSucceedSelector:@selector(didSucceedLogin:)
                                    didFailSelector:@selector(didFailLogin:)
                           downloadProgressDelegate:self
                             uploadProgressDelegate:self];
```

This is how look like method `didFailLogin:`:

```
- (void)didFailLogin:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

And all time I'm getting this error:

> Error Domain=Authentication failed. Code=999 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (Authentication failed. error 999.)"

So what I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you got the Key from photo bucket?

Comment: Sent email request to support

Comment: I have already send the mail, got automated response nothing more ;(